# Change a fraction of values to NA with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, na

I have a large dataframe and would like to replace a random 10% of value1 with NA, and
a different random 20% of value2 with NA

I'm doing this and it works but isn't pretty. Is there a better way?

```
df%>%
  mutate(rand = runif(1:length(df$id)),
         value1 = replace(value1, which(rand < 0.1), NA),
         rand = runif(1:length(df$id)),
         value2 = replace(value2, which(rand < 0.2), NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to extract the repeated parts as a function and replace parts of the vector directly, rather than creating a new column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

replace_with_na <- function(nums, prop) {
  nums[runif(length(nums)) < prop] <- NA
  nums
}

tibble(value1 = 1:100,
       value2 = 101:200) |> 
  mutate(value1 = replace_with_na(value1, 0.1),
         value2 = replace_with_na(value2, 0.2))

#> # A tibble: 100 × 2
#>    value1 value2
#>     <int>  <int>
#>  1      1    101
#>  2      2    102
#>  3      3    103
#>  4     NA     NA
#>  5      5    105
#>  6      6    106
#>  7      7     NA
#>  8      8    108
#>  9      9    109
#> 10     10    110
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

This is essentially just rewriting your code a little, but after defining the function, the ongoing use of it in your actual code looks a little neater.

Answer (score 0):

Use the replacement operator. Not sure what the measure of "pretty" is, but this should be easy to follow.

```
data <- tibble(value1 = 1:100, value2 = 101:200)
rowCt <- NROW(data)

data[sample(rowCt, 0.2*rowCt), "value1"] <- NA
data[sample(rowCt, 0.1*rowCt), "value2"] <- NA
```

While I don't consider your method "unpretty", using a random number generator may not give you exactly the target proportion, especially on small data sets (not sure if this is a concern).

If you're really set on a `tidy` version:

```
data |> 
  mutate(
    value1 = if_else(row_number() %in% sample(n(), 0.2*n()), NA_integer_, value1),
    value2 = if_else(row_number() %in% sample(n(), 0.1*n()), NA_integer_, value2)
  )
```

Personally, if I was reading the code for the first time, I would find it harder to follow what was going on in the `tidy` version